# How to bulk convert row data into columns on Mac Excel (transpose not suitable)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have lots of data that looks like this. It has two columns:

| Name | Email |
| --- | --- |
| bob | bob@example.com |
| bob | bobby@example.com |
| bob | bob1@example.com |
| sally | sally@example.com |
| sally | sallyabc@example.com |

But I need it to look like this. One name per row, with the emails added as extra columns as required. There is an unknown number of emails for each name:

| Name | Email 1 | Email 2 | Email 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | bob@example.com | bobby@example.com | bob1@example.com |
| sally | sally@example.com | sallyabc@example.com |  |

I have to do this for a huge spreadsheet with thousands of rows. So I cannot manually convert each of them using something like transpose. I need a bulk/batch/automated solution.

I know that VBA is a thing that exists, but I don't know how to code it. If that is the solution can you please give me some direction of what the code should look like?

Non-VBA solutions are also very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and starting from this CSV:

```
Name,Email
bob,bob@example.com
bob,bobby@example.com
bob,bob1@example.com
sally,sally@example.com
sally,sallyabc@example.com
```

you can run:

```
mlr --csv nest --ivar ";" -f Email then nest --explode --values --across-fields -f Email then unsparsify input.csv >output.csv
```

to obtain:

| Name | Email_1 | Email_2 | Email_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | bob@example.com | bobby@example.com | bob1@example.com |
| sally | sally@example.com | sallyabc@example.com | - |

Comment: Can Miller also work with Excel files saved with xlsx format?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio No, CSV, TSV, JSON and other file formats https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file-formats.html

Comment: Thanks again! But this is printing the result to terminal. How do I make it output to a csv file?

Comment: @TinyTiger it's the shell: add `>output.csv`. I have edited my answer

Comment: When using output redirection, be incredibly careful about encodings. If you're using cmd you'll get the ANSI charset by default which can be rather problematic.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with your example Column A: Name , Column B: Email

1. Enter this array formula:
   `=INDEX($A$2:$A$6, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:$D1, $A$2:$A$16), 0))`
   into a blank cell, D2, for example, and press Shift + Ctrl + Enter keys together to get the correct result, see screenshot:

[image]

2. Drag the cell down to fill in all values in column D. It will result like in the screenshot above.
3. In cell **E2** where you want your email insert this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$16, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D2:D2,$B$2:$B$16)+IF($A$2:$A$16<>$D2,1,0),0)),"")`
4. Drag the cell right 5-10 cells (or how much you consider is enough) to fill in and then drag the row down to fill in emails for each person.

Result:
[image]

---

**[SOURCE](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3358-excel-transpose-unique-values.html)**

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me because it requires massive amounts of processing. I have 5870 rows to analyze and it won't play nice with that amount of data.

Answer (score 4):

Add an auxiliary column with formula:

```
="Mail "&COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

[image]

Open Power Query Editor - Select **Column1**- go to **Transform**- **Pivot Column**- select **Email** and under *Advanced option* select **Don't Aggregate**:

[image]

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't have that "from sheet" option in my "data" tab. I'm using Excel 2019 on MacOS. Maybe that is why?

Comment: @TinyTiger See if you have From Table/Range,

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I do have From HTML, From Text, and New Database Query when I click on Get External Data in the Data tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you have new Excel version, you can use these formulas.

- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e)
- [`SORT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c)
- [`FILTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

Then you can do it this way:
[image]
The blue [table is named](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-an-excel-table-fbf49a4f-82a3-43eb-8ba2-44d21233b114) `Table1`.

Used formulas:

- E3: `=UNIQUE(Table1[Name])`
- F2:N2: `="Mail"&COLUMN()-COLUMN($E$2)`
- F3 (stretched down): `=INDEX(Table1[Mail];FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE((ROW(Table1[Name])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers];[Name]]))*($E3=Table1[Name]))));TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE((ROW(Table1[Name])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers];[Name]]))*($E3=Table1[Name]))))>0;""))`

Table is filled by SPILL function of the new Excel versions.

Example file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArVkYVSHnABFiiqzBYLPmoubvdHY?e=p7wOeF

In case you are using older Excel version, most of the functionality could be  emulated using array functions. But it becomes much more chaotic...

Comment: I don't have those formulas unfortunately :(